# Exception raise: {%extends "base.html"%} not found, causing "500 Internal Server Error" in Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, jinja2

I currently trying to launch my website with heroku. I watched a yt tutorial and followed all the steps, creating a requirement.txt and Procfile.
The problem occurs when I build my application it successfully deploys it but on the website itself it shows me Internal Server Error.
I have tried to run the app through localhost and it works perfectly.
I also looked up on google and tried many suggestions from different sites without success.

Here is my code:
requirement.txt:

```
bcrypt==3.2.2
certifi==2022.6.15
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
dnspython==2.2.1
email-validator==1.2.1
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-Bcrypt==1.0.1
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.0.1
greenlet==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
pycparser==2.21
requests==2.28.1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.40
tailwind==3.1.5b0
tailwindcss==0.0.1
urllib3==1.26.11
Werkzeug==2.2.2
WTForms==3.0.1
```

Procfile (without .txt):

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

(no change with .txt or not)

route to index.html:

```
@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")
```

index.html:

```
{%extends "base.html"%}
```

I also tried many other ways, like taking all _ out or have '' instead of "".
They all work in localhost but not in heroku

Also base.html is in the same folder as all other templates (folder is called templates)

Thank you so much if you can help!

edit:
This is the log file from heroku:

```
2022-08-23T15:43:58.798987+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.22.132 - - 
[23/Aug/2022:15:43:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.134 Safari/537.36 OPR/89.0.4447.83"

2022-08-23T16:19:26.146143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2022-08-23T16:19:26.150788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2022-08-23T16:19:26.884513+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-08-23T16:19:27.759152+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 16:19:27 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2022-08-23T16:19:27.759453+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 16:19:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2022-08-23T16:19:27.759656+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 16:19:27 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-08-23T16:19:27.763711+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 16:19:27 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-08-23T16:19:27.960098+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 16:19:27 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2022-08-23T16:19:28.110607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-08-23T20:12:39.274284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2022-08-23T20:12:39.286718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2022-08-23T20:12:41.868461+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn main:app`
2022-08-23T20:12:43.054746+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 20:12:43 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2022-08-23T20:12:43.055108+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 20:12:43 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3918 (4)
2022-08-23T20:12:43.055151+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 20:12:43 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-08-23T20:12:43.058698+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 20:12:43 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2022-08-23T20:12:43.080341+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 20:12:43 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-08-23T20:12:43.558705+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-08-23T20:12:44.824631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=theinnerreviewers.herokuapp.com request_id=378490fd-5146-47fb-9f61-141335354858 fwd="31.10.142.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=425ms status=500 bytes=452 protocol=https
2022-08-23T20:12:44.532717+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
2022-08-23T20:12:44.532731+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
2022-08-23T20:12:44.533796+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
2022-08-23T20:12:44.533797+00:00 app[web.1]:   warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826414+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-23 20:12:44,825] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826424+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826425+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826426+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826426+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826427+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826427+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826427+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826427+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826428+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826428+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/theinnerreviewers/routes.py", line 40, in index
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826429+00:00 app[web.1]:     return render_template("index.html")
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826429+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 147, in render_template
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826430+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _render(app, template, context)
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826430+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 130, in _render
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826430+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = template.render(context)
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826430+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1301, in render
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826431+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.environment.handle_exception()
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826431+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 936, in handle_exception
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826431+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826431+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/theinnerreviewers/templates/index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826432+00:00 app[web.1]:     {%extends "base.html"%}
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826433+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 62, in get_source
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826433+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826433+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826433+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise TemplateNotFound(template)
2022-08-23T20:12:44.826434+00:00 app[web.1]: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: base.html
2022-08-23T20:12:44.827771+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.45.191 - - [23/Aug/2022:20:12:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail. On Heroku, you can do this by running [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-logs).

Answer (score 0):

So I finally managed something, what I did and maybe in some other cases that other people had, that I moved my base.html to a second folder called base.
I then wrote the same extends line like that:

```
{% extends "base/base.html"%}
```

what finally worked for me. The last part stays probably with the runtime error but this is done.